# Ruby PTY Commands and Feedback

Tags: ruby, pty

Good Evening,

I am working on a small piece of code to run a curl command to keep a connection open to a server so that I can receive broadcast packets when something changes, like a door is unlocked. I wrote this with Net::HTTPS in Ruby, but the controller I need to run it on conflicts with it. So, I rewrote it using PTY to cURL from Ruby. It works, but every time it disconnects every 30 seconds I need to kill the process and restart it which takes time. I'd like to just keep a PTY session open and just keep running cURL over and over when it disconnects. I'm just not getting anywhere. Below is where I'm at right now. It works for what I need but sometimes it causes macOS to throw a forkpty error and then I have to reboot the Mac mini controller. Well it was doing that before I added the process kill, but it takes a few days to show up if it does. Also, I can't use gems due to install restrictions, only stock Ruby. Thanks again.

```
    fullCommand = "curl -s -k -X #{cmd} '#{url}' #{header}"
loop do
    begin
    PTY.spawn( fullCommand ) do |stdout, stdin, pid|
        begin
        # Send Output to Savant
        stdout.each { |line| parseBcast(line,valuesListID,valuesListFID)}
        $LOG.info("Finished cURL and killing pid: #{pid}")
        Process.kill('QUIT',pid)
        rescue => err
            $LOG.error("Broadcast Exited: #{err}")
            Process.kill('QUIT',pid)
            retry
        end
    rescue => err
        $LOG.error("Broadcast Exited: #{err}")
        Process.kill('QUIT',pid)
        retry
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: _"but the controller I need to run it on conflicts with it"_ – in what regard? If you want to use "only stock Ruby" you should probably fix that problem rather than resorting to an external tool.

Comment: Thanks. So, the way I have to launch the script is from another script. The first script is started by a Savant control system on macOS or Linux. The launch script uses the sockets module and mine uses net::http(s). For some reason the Savant control system loses connection to the first script requiring a restart of the service. Not ideal. I'm just stuck and was hoping I could fix this one way or another. I don't know why the launch script is causing this issue when I use Net::HTTP with my script. There aren't any smoking guns in the debug logs. Anyway, that's for taking the time to respond.